# Communicating between 2 laravel applications

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, acl, hmvc

[image: Applicaton Diagram]

i'm trying to achieve this, different installations of laravel framework on different servers working with each other and sharing resources with the main application(super application) as in the Diagram above.

The super application sits on the main server and houses the user management module which determines who is currently logged into the system. 
and if logged in, you can then load other modules which is another laravel 5 setup that sits on a different server.

these applications work only if a user is logged into the main application. and the Auth->user() object on the Super application is sent to the corresponding applications (A1 and A2) for data entry.

my initial approach was to implement HMVC using laravel 5, but HMVC implies that only one laravel setup be used, which means using only one server. But when you have different applications running seperately on different servers and try to bind it with authentication from a primary application from the main server, i had no idea how possible this is, but i believe it can be done.

Please how do i achieve this, that is how my boss wants it, and insists it be this way.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this topic https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/same-login-on-two-different-laravel-projects?page=1

Comment: ok, @LarsMertens, doing so right away... thanks

Comment: I know, the answer comes much too late, but nowadays they use SSO (Signle-Sign-On).

The user is authenticated in the Super Application and (re)authenticated in the other applications using time-based tokens.

This way works for distributed applications that use the same database

Answer (score 1):

It's a strange setup, but I have two solutions in mind:

1) If your applications can share the same domain you could use a shared cookie. For instance, let's say that your applications are configured as follows:

SA `example.org` (which points at server 1)

A1 `a1.example.org` (which points at server 2)

A2 `a2.example.org` (which points at server 3)

From `SA` you can save an identification cookie for your sub applications (and each Laravel installation can access it).

2) If you can't share the same domain you can login on `SA`, then redirect to your sub applications using some POST data. `A1` or `A2` will be able to gather the identification parameter from the request and save it in the session / cookie to remember you.

Finally, having your identification code, you could write an API to retrieve the user's data.

Comment: my final attempt was to go via API, but if i'd have to do that, its going to be very complex. most especially when you have to render the views independent of the main application. the API would be too tedious...

Comment: Via API you only need to grab data. Then you can populate the objects needed by the secondary application. Maybe in your views you have `{{ \Auth::user()->username }}`, so by scraping the user data you can istantiate a new `Auth` guard and populate it with your user's data. Then everything else will be the same.

Comment: thanks @Vicenzo Maragony ...  i just went through it all, and your response is valid to my quest.... i'd go with the cookie approach.. makes a lot of sense.